# Call javascript function from objective C on orientation change

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, orientation

First off I would like to say I am an absolute Objective C novice.
I have been looking everywhere for a solution for this, but somehow I cannot seem to get it to work.

All I want is to run a Javascript function from Objective C when an orientation change event occurs, seeing how this is the only way to execute Javascript *before* the orientation change animation starts.

I have been able to get a NSLog to show when an orientation change occurs, but no matter what I try, I am unable to execute *any* Javascript. Not even a console.log() or an alert(), let alone the actual function I want to trigger.

Could anyone please save me another afternoon of trial and error?

---

**SOLVED**

Place this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (AppDelegate.m):

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
        selector: @selector(orientationDidChange:)
        name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
        object: nil];
```

And this just below

```
- (void) orientationDidChange: (NSNotification *) note
{
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hideContentsDuringOrientationChange();"];
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have? It shows intent and is a good place for the Informed to help show you what to do. :)

Comment: I added the code I have managed to get working so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [(UIWebView *)self.visibleViewController.view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"someGlobalJSFunction();"];
}
```

Your reference to the UIWebView may have to change based on how your project is setup.

You can use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation for an event after the rotation is complete. I've found this sometimes fires just a bit early for the JS to redraw, though. I fixed that by putting a short timeout in the JS function it calls.

Comment: I placed `[(UIWebView *)self.visibleViewController.view stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"someGlobalJSFunction();"];` in my orientationDidChange function, but it throws the following exception:

-[UIView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd68530

Comment: That probably means self.visibleViewController.view is not referencing the UIWebView.

Comment: I changed the line to `[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hideContentsDuringOrientationChange();"];` and now it works! Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :-)